# TinyMce ImageManager image upload to single/multiple folder that can be accessed by 2 different websites

Tags: hyperlink, tinymce, image-uploading, mcimagemanager

I am using TinyMce Image Manager and using that i want to upload image to single/multiple folder that can be accessed by 2 different websites.

For eg. :-
i have xyz.com and abc.com

i want that whenever i upload images using imagemanager it shows up perfectly in both of them.
How can this be accomplished.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a softlink on you server (which hosts both websites) to make the folder available to both websites.

Comment: As a demonstration i asked for 2 websites...it is more than that...I am creating a portal in which 1 parent website can handle multiple child websites.
In that case it may not be on server.

Comment: your image files are stored on a server :) (all you need to make sure is all your websites are accessing the same directory)

Comment: do you have imagemanager running on one site - if "no" - make this work first, if "yes" - tell me the folder where your uploaded images get stored

Comment: I created a directory in the imagemanager name /files....All the images are getting stored in that directory.
How could i link this to the other website?

Comment: imagemanager name /files   needs to be a link to a central directory, the other websites need to have an imagemanager each linking to the same directory

Comment: whan you set up one of the other websites and you just have installed the imagemanager you delete the files directory and execute somethink like his on your server in order to link it to a central directory: ln -s /source_dir /target_dir

Comment: no this works, please describe what you did already (and what server OS you are using). here is a helpfull link on howto create links on a filesystem: http://freethegnu.wordpress.com/2007/11/15/how-to-create-and-remove-a-soft-link-symlink-or-symbolic-link/